# MVC 4 Tutorial Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently following along with http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-model to get a grasp of MVC 4.

I am trying to add the MoviesController, but whenever I do I receive an error that says:

```
Unable to retrieve metadata for 'MvcMovie.Models.Movie'
unrecognized configuration section entityFramework
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4FFB.tmp line 76)
```

The last thing I did before this was change the Web.config file from the end of the this page.

Comment: restart Visual studio and also IIS express of whatever you u are using as server.

Comment: also, do a clean on the solution

Comment: I restarted both Visual Studio and IIS express and cleaned the solution, and it was promising for a minute but then it gave the same message :P

Comment: I also restarted my entire computer in case there was something else that needed to be restarted that I wasn't aware of, no luck yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it looks like you haven't set up your config settings correctly.

When adding your connection string to the web.config it needs to be added inside the

`<connectionStrings>
</connectionStrings>`

element and make sure you build your project before adding a new controller.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common mistake to put the code in the

```
<configSections></configSections>
```

instead of putting it in the

```
<connectionStrings></connectionStrings>
```

That should fix the problem